# WinBio Save Capture Sample as Image - Unable to read from memory

Tags: c++, biometrics

I'm C++ newbie and need to save image [captured by Biometric fingerprint sensor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401603(v=vs.85).aspx) as bmp image file. I've found that [this](https://github.com/djbozkosz/Windows-Biometric-Framework-FingerPrint-Example) example might be suitable for my requirements, but while I'm running the application (as administrator), I've got error while trying to get pointer `&sample` says `'Unable to read from memory'`

```
    HRESULT CaptureSample()
    {
      HRESULT hr = S_OK;
      WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle = NULL;
      WINBIO_UNIT_ID unitId = 0;
      WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL rejectDetail = 0;
      PWINBIO_BIR sample = NULL;
      SIZE_T sampleSize = 0;
      // Connect to the system pool & opening session code done successfully. 
      // Capture a biometric sample.
      std::cout << "Calling WinBioCaptureSample - Swipe sensor...\n";

      hr = WinBioCaptureSample(
        sessionHandle,
        WINBIO_NO_PURPOSE_AVAILABLE,
        WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_RAW,
        &unitId,
        &sample, // Here Application crashes and error is 'Unable to read from memory'
        &sampleSize,
        &rejectDetail
        );

      std::cout << "Swipe processed - Unit ID: " << unitId << "\n";


      if(FAILED(hr))
      {
        if(hr == WINBIO_E_BAD_CAPTURE)
          std:: cout << "Bad capture; reason: " << rejectDetail << "\n";
        else
          std::cout << "WinBioCaptureSample failed.hr = 0x" << std::hex << hr << std::dec << "\n";

        if(sample != NULL)
        {
          WinBioFree(sample);
          sample = NULL;
        }

        if(sessionHandle != NULL)
        {
          WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
          sessionHandle = NULL;
        }

        return hr;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You did not open the session with WinBioOpenSession

Comment: It's already opened but just to make code shorter I didn't add it.

Comment: I'm using same code in this sample: https://github.com/djbozkosz/Windows-Biometric-Framework-FingerPrint-Example

Comment: This is exactly the sample in the official doc here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401603.aspx so your code has to have something different. Please post a full reproducing code if you want help.

Comment: I've just cloned this repo and debug it without any change (current user is administrator & Visual studio opened as administrator)

Comment: For more info, it has been mentioned in Docs this note "[WinBioCaptureSample has been deprecated and may be altered or unavailable after Windows 10, version 1607]" but my windows version is Windows 10 PRO 1511 so it should not be changed, and if it is changed, I couldn't find any updated documentation by MSDN

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine in the git repo, so if you haven't modified anything, then my guess would be:
  a) something is already using the device (this was the case when we had a similar problem)
  b) driver or connection error